# Blender 2.93.6 LTS Crashing mid-render after approx 3 hours like clockwork

Tags: gpu, renderman-render-engine

Perhaps its coincidence, but my primary render server crashes like clockwork about 3 hours into rendering an animation, regardless of how many frames it crunches.

I ran it with blender_debug_gpu_glitchworkaround last night and I see the following critical error before the app crashed completely:

```
An application exception has occurred in blender.exe.
  Error codes: 0x00007FFACDE5B96B 0xC0000005 0x00000000 (0x00000001) (0x00000000)
*** exception ***
Pixar PhotoRealistic RenderMan 24.4
copyright (c) 1988-2022 Pixar.
linked Fri Apr 15 20:27:27 2022 Pacific Daylight Time @2226585
build windows10_x86-64_vc14icc190_external_release

Rendered on Wed Sep 14 22:25:53 Pacific Daylight Time 2022
Rendering at 1920x1080 pixels, 512 maxsamples
    "NULL_Ci" (mode = Ci_variance_auto, type = null)
    "C:\tmp\renderman_for_blender\C00S09-S10\images\v001_t01\Scene.View_Layer.0044.exr" (mode = Ci,a, type = blender)

         Total heap mem: 53427.86 MB
       Max resident mem: 54591.12 MB
            Page faults: 376596659
       Real time:     01:56
       User time:     3:17:14
       Sys time:      02:47
```

Im not sure if this is directly related to Renderman, or Blender. But im really hoping others have  found a solution to this issue.

TIA!

Comment: How much memory does your system have? Is it more than 54.6 GB of RAM? If not you're running out of memory.

Comment: I see. Only 64GB on this system, this looks like a running out of RAM issue?

Comment: EDIT : Heres a screen shot of the render system performing the same task this AM. I would assume the RAM usage last night would echo this graph, it was the same frames/scenes in Blender. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HvpBg8WBKc-JOmhLWBedvfwOqVgK7eua/view?usp=sharing